# EC2 - Total bandwidth In/Out from a particular instance over a particular period

Tags: amazon-ec2, bandwidth

I would like to know the total bandwidth used by a particular EC2 instance this month.

I am being billed for 25TB of data transfer by AWS - and I would like to know where the issue is. I may have instances communicating to each other via Public IP addresses (which is chargeable).

Is there a way to see each instance's bathwidth usage over a specific period?

Comment: You might have had a malicious script run on your site to download files over and over. This is actually common and one of the main reasons that Amazon and other hosting companies prompt you to set bandwidth limits. Sadly, if its external traffic than Amazon will expect you to foot the bill. 25 TB is around 338.38 US Dollar I believe... count your self lucky its not 250 TB :)

Comment: I noticed a lot of traffic between our production and database server.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't enabled hourly or daily Cost and Usage detail reports, do that now.  These reports break down everything that generates a charge, by resource-id and the exact type of usage that generated the charge -- so traffic to the Internet, traffic using public IP addresses, etc., is all broken down by the specific instance, balancer, bucket, etc., that generated the traffic.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports-costusage.html

For a coarse view, check the instance metrics for `NetworkIn` and `NetworkOut` metrics for each instance, in CloudWatch.  These are *all* traffic for the instances, including internal traffic not crossing availability zone boundaries.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html

Load Balancers also have coarse metrics for bytes processed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/elb-metricscollected.html